# How to make joined calls using Ebay SDK using davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php?

Tags: php, mysql, sdk, ebay-api

Before asking the question, I'm an admitted novice with the SDK and all of it is a struggle for me right now, in addition, I think I may not fully understand the policies/limits of Ebay yet. I'm not sure what is "allowed" or "proper" so I don't get blocked for improper use (like too many calls or something like that).

*The question:* Can you call for a request inside a loop of another request, similar to MySQL/PHP when you first request the ID's and them loop over them to return the details?

Example: I would want to look up targeted ebay-motors sellers, return a set number or keyword search group of listings from those sellers. (I believe the SDK handles this as one request - ItemFilter SellerID / Keywords)

Then, for each listing I'd want the listed compatible vehicles for each listing (this being the "2nd" loop/request per listing).

This is my "logic" (or lack there of) to get the result I want. If I can't use loops but I can "join" listing to compatibles like a spreadsheet might look, that would work too.

```
//Two responses?..one from each request
$response = $service->findItemsAdvanced($request);

// how to get compatibles from item id in request/response 1 ?//
$response2 = $service-> /* ??? */  ($request2);


// Iterate over the items returned in the response.
foreach ($response->searchResult->item as $item) {
    //an easy var name for reference
    var mylistId = $item->itemId, 
    // lets the see the ID's //
    printf(  
        "(%s) %s\n",
        $item->itemId,
        $item->title
    );

   //maybe the request and response is in the loop???
   // $requestTWO = get compatibles linked to mylistId
   // $responseTWO = return compatibles
   foreach ($responseTWO->searchResult->item as $compats) {
       // print new responses
       printf(  
        "(%s) %s\n",
        $compats->make, 
        $compats->model,
        $compats->year
    );
}
```

This seems like overkill to have a new request for more details.

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible and there is nothing wrong with your logic.  I can provide an in-depth answer soon. Just need some time to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Finding service does not return the compatibility information that you need. For each item that is returned you will have to make a separate call to GetSingleItem in Shopping service.

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Sdk;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Finding;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping;

$sdk = new Sdk([
    'credentials' => [
        'devId' => 'DEV ID',
        'appId' => 'APP ID',
        'certId' => 'CERT ID',
    ],
    'globalId'    => Constants\GlobalIds::MOTORS
]);

/**
 * Create the service objects.
 */
$finding = $sdk->createFinding([
    'apiVersion' => '1.13.0'
]);

$shopping = $sdk->createShopping([
    'apiVersion' => '981'
]);

/**
 * Create the finding request.
 */
$findingRequest = new Finding\Types\FindItemsAdvancedRequest();
/**
 * Ask for items from these sellers. You specify up to 100 sellers.
 */
$itemFilter = new Finding\Types\ItemFilter();
$itemFilter->name = 'Seller';
$itemFilter->value = [
    'brakemotive76',
    'primechoiceautoparts'
];
$findingRequest->itemFilter[] = $itemFilter;
/**
 * You can optionally narrow the search down further by only requesting
 * listings that match keywords or categories.
 */
//$request->keywords = 'Brake Pads';
//$request->categoryId = ['33560', '33561'];

/**
 * eBay can return more than one page of results.
 * So just start at page 1 to begin with.
 */
$findingRequest->paginationInput = new Finding\Types\PaginationInput();
$pageNum = 1;

do {
    $findingRequest->paginationInput->pageNumber = $pageNum;

    $findingResponse = $finding->findItemsAdvanced($findingRequest);

    // Handle any errors returned from the API.
    if (isset($findingResponse->errorMessage)) {
        foreach ($findingResponse->errorMessage->error as $error) {
            printf(
                "%s: %s\n\n",
                $error->severity=== Finding\Enums\ErrorSeverity::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
                $error->message
            );
        }
    }

    if ($findingResponse->ack !== 'Failure') {
        /**
         * For each item make a second request to the Shopping service to get the compatibility information.
         */
        foreach ($findingResponse->searchResult->item as $item) {
            $shoppingRequest = new Shopping\Types\GetSingleItemRequestType();
            $shoppingRequest->ItemID = $item->itemId;
            /**
             * We have to tell the Shopping service to return the comaptibility and item specifics information as
             * it will not by default.
             */
            $shoppingRequest->IncludeSelector = 'ItemSpecifics, Compatibility';

            $shoppingResponse = $shopping->getSingleItem($shoppingRequest);

            if (isset($shoppingResponse->Errors)) {
                foreach ($shoppingResponse->Errors as $error) {
                    printf(
                        "%s: %s\n%s\n\n",
                        $error->SeverityCode === Shopping\Enums\SeverityCodeType::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
                        $error->ShortMessage,
                        $error->LongMessage
                    );
                }
            }

            if ($shoppingResponse->Ack !== 'Failure') {
                $item = $shoppingResponse->Item;

                print("\n$item->Title\n");

                if (isset($item->ItemSpecifics)) {
                    print("\nThis item has the following item specifics:\n\n");
                    foreach ($item->ItemSpecifics->NameValueList as $nameValues) {
                        printf(
                           "%s: %s\n",
                            $nameValues->Name,
                             implode(', ', iterator_to_array($nameValues->Value))
                        );
                    }
                }    

                if (isset($item->ItemCompatibilityCount)) {
                    printf("\nThis item is compatible with %s vehicles:\n\n", $item->ItemCompatibilityCount);

                    foreach ($item->ItemCompatibilityList->Compatibility as $compatibility) {
                        foreach ($compatibility->NameValueList as $nameValues) {
                            if ($nameValues->Name != '') {
                                printf(
                                    "%s: %s\n",
                                    $nameValues->Name,
                                    implode(', ', iterator_to_array($nameValues->Value))
                                );
                            }
                        }
                        printf("Notes: %s \n", $compatibility->CompatibilityNotes);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $pageNum += 1;

} while ($pageNum <= $findingResponse->paginationOutput->totalPages);
```

Comment: Thanks David, I wasn't sure if requesting in a loop was improper, your example is thorough and clear, I very much appreciate it.

Comment: David, you called compatibility because shopping did not return it on its own (if I understand your note)... where are the manufacturer numbers (what is the "call")  .. I thinks its called item details in the eBay listing creator.  -   Ebay Motors is quite the challenge it seems

Comment: Manufacturer Part Number is normally stored in what eBay call the Item Specifics. I've updated the example so that it also gets the item specifics.  To find the MPN you will have to do something along the lines of if($nameValues->Name === 'Manufacturer Part Number') { $mpn = $nameValues->Value[0]; } This is because the item specifics does not have a specific field for MPN.

Comment: Thanks David, I figured it our around 2 AM. I "included the selector" for Items Specifics, then converted them to an array.  ....The example you've provided is a great complete example of dealing with Ebay Motors, I think its a great contribution to Stack' in the long term considering how fast Ebay Motors is growing. My project has taken a huge leap forward, thanks.